# Postgresql simple query takes too much time like five minutes to execute

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

a very simple postgres query, like `SELECT` takes five minutes to execute. It was working fine, taking less than one second and at some point the execution time increased significantly to five minutes. When I do `SELECT` query to another table in the same database - it works pretty fast. Only one table is affected and it seems to happen at some point, before it was also executing fast. Following query takes five minutes to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
```

another thing is that if I select by Id - it works instantly, very fast, less than one second:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = '33ae0b5f0d6a0435e36faf8d';
```

UPDATE 1

table definition has 34 columns,

Id primary key column is indexed, it is GUID not integer

table contains only 8455 rows

```
server_prod=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table;
 count 
-------
  8455
(1 row)
```

UPDATE 2

```
server_prod=# select current_setting('shared_buffers') AS shared_buffers, pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('some_table')) AS table_size;
 shared_buffers | table_size 
----------------+------------
 128MB          | 62 GB
(1 row)

server_prod=# explain (analyze, buffers, timing) SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..9677.70 rows=10 width=1379) (actual time=363665.384..363668.365 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5701604 read=1443335
   ->  Seq Scan on project_views  (cost=0.00..8109910.80 rows=8380 width=1379) (actual time=363665.381..363668.358 rows=10 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=5701604 read=1443335
 Planning time: 0.099 ms
 Execution time: 363668.414 ms
(6 rows)
```

UPDATE 3

psql version is 10.7

```
server_prod=# SELECT version();
                                                                   version                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

please advise.

Comment: NB A `limit` clause without an `order by`clause is meaningless. If the table is updated/exported/imported/partitioned etc the order rows will be returned in can change.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: It seems your table is severely bloated. That many shared buffer  hits for only 8455  rows looks bad. Run `vacuum full some_table;` then try again

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion if it's some kind of attack, what is the way to figure out rows that contain most data? is there any command to sort it out by row size? In other words, I want to find out what rows contain most of the data.

Comment: A bloated table has nothing to do with an "attack". It simply means that for some reason autovacuum wasn't able to clean up properly. More often than not this is caused by not ending transactions properly. `vacuum full` will remove that bloat. The Postgres Wiki contains some queries to investigate this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `vacuum full some_table;` solved the problem, thanks for clarifying it

Comment: @Colin'tHart to be pedantic, LIMIT 50 without ORDER BY has a meaning: *"Give me 50 rows from the table, I don't care which ones"* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) says:

It seems your table is severely bloated. That many shared buffer hits for only 8455 rows looks bad. Table bloat means that for some reason autovacuum wasn't able to clean it up. More often than not this is caused by not ending transactions properly.

The Postgres Wiki contains [some queries](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat) to investigate the bloat.

Run `vacuum full some_table`, which will remove that bloat,  then try your query again.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `LIMIT` clause, it is applied after all the data is loaded to filter down the data, which is evident by your `EXPLAIN` as it is the last operation (top of the operation chain). This is because `LIMIT` isn't a predicate filter, rather it just takes the top N number of rows from the total result set. While 8,455 rows is tiny, the actual Table size is 62 GB on disk which is a decent amount of data to `SELECT` all at once and then filter and return to the client.

When you use the `WHERE` clause, the filtering is applied upfront, and can be done efficiently because your `id` field is indexed, so very few rows need to actually be analyzed to serve the data (since the logical data structure is a B-Tree) and therefore much less data (in file size) to load and process.

If you want a more efficient way to get only 50 records back, you'll need to find a way to use predicate filtering with your `WHERE` clause to reduce the data first, and then apply your `TOP` if needed. E.g. if you know you which range of `ids` to filter on (though I'm assuming since you're using a `GUID` that'll be hard to do). If there are other fields you can use to help filter down the data with predicate filtering, then you should create indexes on those fields as well, but that will depend on your table definition.

Comment: The actual stats says only 10 rows were actually read from the table: `Seq Scan on project_views: ...(actual time=363665.381..363668.358 rows=10 loops=1)`. Suggesting that the limit clause was sensibly applied as soon as it could be.

Comment: @AndrewSayer Yes and no. The entire set of data still needed to be loaded from disk first before it could be applied, there's no way around that (without use of an index). Which again, isn't a lot of rows per se, but the table itself is *big enough* in size when being fully loaded from disk, to make a difference. Perhaps a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion of `VACUUM`ing the table will correct that issue though.

Comment: @J.D. please provide a source for this claim (that the entire set of data is needed to be loaded from disk first before LIMIT can be applied). It sounds completely wrong.